Openai gpt structure output: Invalid schema for response_format, parameters exceeds limit of 100
Working with structured output feature of gpt4-o, I had this error message. How can I fix this error besides reducing the number of parameters?

Error message: openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error':
{'message': "Invalid schema for response_format 'create_structure':
103 parameters exceeds limit of 100.", 'type':
'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'response_format', 'code': None}}


https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/structured-outputs/supported-schemas:

A schema may have up to 100 object properties total, with up to 5 levels of nesting.

Your call has too many object properties. Only workaround I can think of is splitting your call into 2 calls.
